# Pandas: чтение Excel с объединенными ячейками и пустыми значениями

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть Excel файл с объединенными ячейками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу код:

`df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name='Лист1')`

Pandas выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При написание заполнение:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name='Лист1').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось что бы выдавал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делать это надо не вручную!
Это просто пример
Помоги пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте в fillna добавить параметр axis=1 (или =0, я всё время путаю)

Comment: @CrazyElf я запоминал просто - нулевой индекс - ряды, чтоб по ним идти, пишем axis=0, строки первый индекс, axis=1, и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Укажите ось, чтоб заполнялось по строкам

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
```

Comment: Тогда 2 а будет пустым

Comment: что такое два а ? и приведите данные текстом

Comment: он тогда выведет 1 столбец под индексом 2 'Nan'

Comment: да, конечно.  но вы можете проверить, что остались nan и сделать заполненеие по вертикальной оси. Но, на самом деле, если у вас в середине встретятся вертикально объединенные ячейки, ошибок не избежать. нужно анализировать сам excel

Comment: В этом и проблема, нужно большой файл вывести в питоне, с соединенными ячейками и пустыми

Answer (score 1):

действительно, для произвольных - вертикальных и горизонтальных объединений ячеек - в старых xls решения в сети есть, а вот что касается openpyxl есть проблемы

одна из них в том, что если открывать файл через read_excel, то он отрывается в readonly режиме, и почему-то openpyxl для этого случая имеет отдельный класс для worksheet с ограниченной функциональностью, не позволяющей получить информацию об объединенных ячейках. В коде ниже я открываю поэтому файл дважды. Ну а остальное дело техники

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('Книга1.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1')
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Книга1.xlsx')
sheet = excel.worksheets[0]

for r in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
    cl, rl, cr, rr = r.bounds  # границы объединенной области
    rl -= 2
    rr -= 1
    cl -= 1
    base_value = df.iloc[rl, cl]
    df.iloc[rl:rr, cl:cr] = base_value

print(df)
```

получается, что и хотелось

до

```
     a    b    c    d
0    a  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    b    c    v    j
2  NaN    f    g    k
3  NaN    a  NaN    m
4    c    v    b    n
```

после

```
     a    b    c    d
0    a    a    a    a
1    b    c    v    j
2    b    f    g    k
3  NaN    a    a    m
4    c    v    b    n
```

Comment: А если большое количество строк и столбцов можно как-то это оптимизировать?

Comment: оптимизировать врядли. это же информация из эксель файла берется, и надо одну ячейку раскладывать в слайс. не представляю, что можно ускорить